# Android: how to define image parameters (size? format? filesize) when using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, camera, size, format

I have an application that has a feature of taking a picture.
The image I take has a defined size Height x Width.

I am using the intent MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.
Can I maniuplate these parameters somehow?

I found other solution - to create my own camera activity using SurfaceView as specified in the link:
[http://itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/mobilemedia_spring10/androidCamera101.pdf][1]

Then i guess I can manipulate the image taken before saving it.

Is it a good way?
Can I keep using the MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent?
What is usually done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experience u can't set the size of the image by supplying parameter to this intent. 
If u will add something like this 
`intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,location_of_image_to_save);`
,it will return you the picture of default size set by your camera . Later u can change the size of the image using this code

```
            int width = photo.getWidth();
            int height = photo.getHeight();
            int newWidth =3000;
            int newHeight =3000; 
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;// calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

            // createa matrix for the manipulation
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // resize the bit map
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            // rotate the Bitmap


            // recreate the new Bitmap
            Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0,width, height, matrix, true);
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: Why scale when it is taking at the lowest resolution? (it's by default) 320x640 something closer to that.